# ros2 on embedded board without any network connection

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-crystal, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A very simple question on ROS2,

Can we use ROS2 on embedded platform/board without any network connection (no internet/no router) means standalone board only ?

I tried running ROS2 without any network connectivity on laptop but it is not able to create any topic, services.  (And works well with network connectivity)

Is it like ROS2 always need some router/network connectivity to run ROS nodes? (can't run on standalone board)

please help in understanding ROS2 concepts.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325872/ros2-on-embedded-board-without-any-network-connection/) by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-06-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-15**:
I believe the issue is not "with or without a network connection", it is that some DDS implementations ignore `lo` (ie: `localhost`) network interfaces. They should be configurable to enable the `lo` interface as well and then everything should work as normal.

See [ros2/rmw_fastrtps#228](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/issues/228), [eProsima/Fast-RTPS#167](https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-RTPS/issues/167) and [eProsima/Fast-RTPS#267](https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-RTPS/pull/267) for what I believe are related issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn Thanks for your reference links.

This one solves my problem  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30982079/6920365

> You can use multicast on loopback but
> you have to add a new route because
> your OS using default external
> interface by default for multicast.
> Also multicast can be disabled by
> default on loopback. On linux you can
> change this with this command:

```
route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev lo
ifconfig lo multicast
```

To check loopback, run this command: (make you are disconnected from all network connectivity)

Terminal 1: `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker`
Terminal 2: `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener`

---

Originally posted by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) with karma: 115 on 2019-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2